# C++: operator precedence from a Stroustrup example

Tags: c++

Stroustrup C++ 4th Ed Page 197 has the following examples, which result in an incrementing stream of characters printed until `null` and not `"abc"`.  Questions: how is the `++*p` being evaluated?  `++` and `*` are the same precedence and evaluation right-to-left, therefore it's my understanding `*p` is evaluated first, leading to the character `p` points to, then this character is incremented by `++`.  Is this understanding correct?  Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void fp(char* p)
{
    while (*p)
        cout << ++*p;
}

void fr2(char& r)
{
    char* p = &r;
    while (*p)
        cout << ++*p;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char s[] = "abc";
    char *p = s;

    fp(p);
    fr2(*p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no possible ambiguity here. Consider `*p++` instead.

Comment: Thanks I'm aware that `*p++` should be used to print the string.  I'm just going by Stroustrup's example, which does not appear in his erratta http://www.stroustrup.com/4th_printing3.html

Comment: I'm going with "that's a bug". Besides that book is a little out of date, so you should probably look for a more modern reference.

Comment: My point was that `++*p` is unambiguously parsed as `++(*p)` without considering precedence and associativity at all. These rules are needed only to resolve ambiguities. In contrast, `*p++` **is** ambiguous, and we need some rules to resolve ambiguity.

Comment: @Evg how is `*p++` ambiguous?  In modern interpretations ++ is higher precedence than *, because ++ is postfix, the operation is performed after the line is evaluated.  Resulting in dereference of p used as the value for the expression, then increment the pointer.  I believe in K&R `*` and `++` (postfix or prefix) are same precedence, but the assoc is right-to-left.  It still results in the above mentioned evaluation.

Comment: `*p++` is ambiguous *before* considering precedence and associativity rules. It can be parsed as `(*p)++` and `*(p++)`. These rules tell a parser how it should actually be parsed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right about the precedence and the associativity. This expression:

```
++*p;
```

is parsed as

```
++(*p);
```

i.e. first the indirection of `p` is done, and then the value returned is incremented.

This means that in the while loop:

```
while (*p)
    cout << ++*p;
```

the pointer `p` is never actually incremented. This results in an infinite loop where just the value of `p[0]` is incremented forever.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/faC0zr), which shows the output as a very long sequence of ascii values starting from `a`. Note that `abc` is *not* printed.

By the same reasoning, the expression:

```
*++p;
```

is parsed as:

```
*(++p);
```

which is fine, since the pointer is incremented first, and then the pointer is dereferenced.

Comment: Why is precedence important here? What would change if `++` had higher/lower precedence than `*`?

Comment: @Evg That would affect which operator is evaluated first. Since pre-increment, and indirection have the same precedence, associativity kicks in. edited the answer as well.

Comment: I don't think this is true. How could `++*p` ever be parsed as something other than `++(*p)`? In contrast, `*p++` could be parsed as `*(p++)` and `(*p)++`.

Comment: The code is essentially incrementing the value of `*p` until `*p == 0`.  Because `++` is prefix, the increment occurs before `cout` is called each time.  That's what I can tell.

Comment: @Evg agreed, I'm not saying `++*p` can be parsed as anything else. (given the precedence and associativity of these operators).

Comment: Then precedence and associativity don't play any role in `++*p`. They do in `*p++`.

Comment: @Evg I'm not sure what you mean. Associativity *is* what makes it parse as `++(*p)`. I'm not suggesting there's any other way to parse it, but it's consistent with associativity.

Comment: Suppose that associativity is left-to-right instead. Would `++*p` be parsed as `(++*)p` then? Would `++*p` be ill-formed without parentheses?

Comment: @Evg Yes, I suppose if associativity were left-to-right for these operators, then it would be ill-formed without parentheses.

Comment: And I guess it would not because there is no other way to parse it. We need these rules only to resolve ambiguities. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @Evg I see what you're saying, but my interpretation is slightly different: we might need rules to avoid ambiguities, but those rules must be applicable anyway. If a rule makes something ill-formed, even though there would be no ambiguity otherwise, that's just unfortunate :)